# How to validate a number entered in the edittext? - android

Tags: java, android, validation, numbers, android-edittext

well am able to validate an edittext when its empty using the below code

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1); 

if ((a.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value is empty", 0).show();
}
```

the *edittext* input type is set as number.

now i want to validate the number entered.

for example the range of number to be entered should be between 15 to 25.

if the number is below 15 or above 25 it should show **Out of Range**

help me out! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
final int value = Integer.valueOf(a.getText().toString());  
if (value < 15 || value > 25) {  
    // do what you want  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Parse the value to Integer or Float and do your validation.

```
Integer.parseInt(a.getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the value entered is a number you can first parse it using either:
`int val = Integer.parseInt(a.getText());`
or if it is a float:
`float val = Float.parseFloat(a.getText());`.

Then you can just do a comparison: `if( val < min || val > max ) //show message`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check decimal number is valid or not valid:

```
public boolean isValidDecimalNumber(EditText editText) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString().trim()) && !editText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(".");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

First check Edittext is null
Second check Edittext is value grater than 0

```
String amount1 = edtAmount1.getText().toString().trim();
            if( amount1.length() == 0 || Double.valueOf(amount1)<1){
                Toast.makeText(StudentfeepayActivity.this,"Enter fee amount",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
```